# How can I extract map keys from generic argument that can be a Record OR function that returns Record?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a function, that takes an argument.

The argument can be one of:

- a `Record<key?, SomeType>`
- a `(arg: AnotherType) => Record<key?, SomeType>`

How can I make the function's return type match a new `Record<key?, string>`, where `key?` is determined by the user input?

This is a summary of what I tried:

```
export type MyMapType<
  Key extends string | number | symbol,
  RecordType extends Record<string, any>,
  SomeTypeExt extends SomeType = SomeType
> = Record<Key, RecordType> | ((intermediateArg: SomeTypeExt) => Record<Key, RecordType>);

export function myFn<
  RecordType extends Record<string, any>,
  SomeTypeExt extends SomeType = SomeType,
  Key extends string | number | symbol = string | number | symbol
>(arg: MyMapType<Key, RecordType, SomeTypeExt>): (intermediateArg: RecordType) => Record<Key, string> {
  return aMappingFunction(arg);
}

// example types
type SomeType = Record<string, string>;
type RecordTypeExt = Record<string, any>;

// mapping function
function aMappingFunction<T extends Record<string, any>>(arg: T): (arg: any) => Record<keyof typeof arg, any> {
  return () => {
    //   loops through object keys/values, re-maps to `Record<keyof typeof arg, MoreComplexType>`
    return {} as any;
  };
}
```

However when I use the function, like this:

```
const myFnRes = myFn<RecordTypeExt>({
  expectedKey: {
    // object contents
  },
});
```

The return type is:

```
ReturnType<typeof myFnRes> // => Record<string | number | symbol, string>
```

I am looking for the correct way to make it return this type instead:

```
ReturnType<typeof myFnRes> // => Record<'expectedKey', string>
```

How can I achieve this?

I failed to use `infer` as I didn't manage to understand where and how to use it in this complex context, I failed to find examples that helped me figure it out.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLlKvm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Added the updated playground link

Comment: Please provide the example as plain text in the body of your post.  A playground link is a great supplement but is not a substitute for a self-contained example.

Comment: It's pretty much the same code - I can't share the exact source as it is proprietary, I only obfuscated the names. The types themselves ar equal.

Comment: You're not understanding.  Please put the code from your Playground link directly into the question.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to manually specify `RecordTypeExt` when you call `myFn`?  TypeScript doesn't currently have partial type parameter inference, so when you specify `RecordTypeExt` you are getting the default values for the other two parameters; you're not getting inference.  If you can have all three inferred like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGP30w), then it might behave better. If you must specify one and want the others inferred then you need a workaround like currying; perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wggP1w).  Which approach works better for you?

Comment: I updated, and also thanks for the comment. I do need to pass the type manually as this type is used inside the argument as a possible input in one of the keys, as a function that uses this type. The 2nd approach indeed work! :) I was hoping to avoid having to call it twice like this. Maybe I will be able to wrap it one more time to avoid this.

Comment: Okay, so I'm going to close this as a duplicate of other questions where the issue is how to manually specify one type parameter and have the others be inferred.  (Otherwise I'll end up writing an answer nearly identical to those).  If you don't think that's appropriate, please [edit] the question to clearly distinguish your needs from those of the other question.  Good luck!